# Is there a fast way in the "data.table" package to add a date and numeric variable together?

Tags: r, data.table

I currently have a data table called "DT" that has three columns and 300 million rows. As an example, I am trying to add a date column to a numeric column for a small subset of "DT":

```
DT = data.table(x=as.Date("2012-01-01"), y=1:9)


DT        
            x y
1: 2012-01-01 1
2: 2012-01-01 2
3: 2012-01-01 3
4: 2012-01-01 4
5: 2012-01-01 5
6: 2012-01-01 6
7: 2012-01-01 7
8: 2012-01-01 8
9: 2012-01-01 9
```

My code looks like:

```
DT[,z:=sum(x,y)]
```

However, when I do this, I get the error:

```
Error in Summary.Date(c(15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340,  :
```

sum not defined for "Date" objects

Now, the code work when I do,

```
DT[,z:=x+y]
```

the code works, BUT, is much much slower than the option above.

Is there a fast and easy way to add numeric variables to date formats that works when I have hundreds of millions of rows? Thanks!

Comment: `sum` adds up all the values in both `x` and `y` to return one result, `+` adds each individual row of `x` and `y` together. One is a more complicated calculation and assignment I imagine. You're comparing apples to oranges. `DT[, z:=sum(as.numeric(x),y) ]` won't throw an error, but it will give you the same result for every value of `z`.

Comment: How slow is very slow by the way? Are we talking minutes? Hours? Or a handful of seconds? I can do `DT[,z:=x+y]` on 100 million rows in 2.09 seconds.